# Python request.get not getting all <div>

Tags: python, get, request

I am making a get request to https://racing.appledaily.com.hk/race-day/race-position?raceDay=1865&race=15632 with a chrome's developer page, i can see a full html page. However when i make a get request, python only returns part of the html.

HTML:

```
<html class="gr__racinng_applledaily_com_hk" style='overflow: initial;">
<head> ... </head>
<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
<!-- Google Tag Mananger (noscript) -->
<noscript> ...</noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Mananger (noscript) -->
<div data-v-6223d6a8 id="app" class="web"> ... </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the `<div data-v-6223d6a8 id="app" class="web"> ... </div>` part is missing

Code Used :

```
content = request.get('https://racing.appledaily.com.hk/race-day/race-position?raceDay=1865&race=15632')
```

Answer (score 0):

Request gets the HTML from the source. When you use the inspector you see the full HTML because your browser renders the rest of the HTML. To get the full HTML look into Scrapy Splash or Selenium.